# What css stylesheet is used by linkedin, facebook or quora

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have been wondering that how linkedin , facebook or quora design their websites. When I saw their website in responsive mode in the browser then I found out that their websites get fixed at point 1000px or 1100px and the content does not change but when I see their website on mobile then it looks ok.  How do they do that?

Edit:-
In order to make question more specific. Just open your browser and visit linkedin, quora or facebook. Toogle responsive mode(in firefox ctrl+shift+m) and keep doing the size of the screen smaller slowly then below the point 1000px or 1100px the content get fixed and it does not change. I am familiar with media queries  and according to media queries content should response according to the page like this current page where you are reading this question.Try to toogle the responsive mode and see how the content of this current page response to the different screen size but in case of linkedin, facebook or quora below point 1000px and 1100px the content does not response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use @media directive. It is useful for making breakpoints. Some examples:

```css
/*--- Example 1 ---*/

/* Normally .box is 100% width */
.box {
  width: 100%;
}
/* But on screens with width > 100px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  /* It is only 50% width */
  .box {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/*--- Example 2 ---*/

/*If screen is 200px width or smaller*/
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  /*Show special warning*/
  .too-small-browser {
    display: block;
  }
}

/*--- Example 3 ---*/

/* @media can be used not only for responsive resize */
@media print {
  /*Hide .navbar, .ads, and .footer while printing*/
  .navbar, .ads, .footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: Thanks for you nice answer. I really appreciate it.